# Symfony Data Transform and Update Form With The Data

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

Between 2 entities exists OneToMany relationship. First is User Entity second is Domains entities. One user can have multiple domains.

This is Users Entity (removed other fields because unrelated with subject):

```
class Users extends BaseUser
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\UsersBundle\Entity\UserDomains" , mappedBy="user" , cascade={"all"})
     */
    protected $domains;
    /**
     * Add domain
     *
     * @param \UsersBundle\Entity\UserDomains $domain
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function addDomain(\UsersBundle\Entity\UserDomains $domain)
    {
        $this->domains[] = $domain;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove domain
     *
     * @param \UsersBundle\Entity\UserDomains $domain
     */
    public function removeDomain(\UsersBundle\Entity\UserDomains $domain)
    {
        $this->domains->removeElement($domain);
    }
}
```

This is UserDomains Entity (some fields has been removed):

```
class UserDomains
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AffiliateBundle\Entity\Users", inversedBy="domains")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param integer $user
     *
     * @return UserDomains
     */
    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return UserDomains
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Must be add a domain when register user to system. I have got RegisterType for registration form. This type form class has got DataTransformer for adding domain which register user.

RegisterType class is here:

```
class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('fullName', 'text', array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control'), 'label' => 'user_register.fullname', 'translation_domain' => 'UsersBundle'))
            ->add('domains', 'text', array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control select2', 'id' => 'select2_sample1')))
        ;

        $builder->get('domains')->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
            function(){
                return '';
            },
            function($data){

                $arrCollection = new ArrayCollection();

                if (strpos($data, ",") !== false) {
                    $expData = explode(',', $data);
                    foreach ($expData as $domain) {
                        $domainObj = new UserDomains();
                        $domainObj->setName($domain);
                        $domainObj->setEnabled(true);
                        $arrCollection->add($domainObj);
                    }
                } else if (!empty($data)) {
                    $domain = new UserDomains();
                    $domain->setName($data);
                    $domain->setEnabled(true);
                    $arrCollection->add($domain);
                }

                return $arrCollection;
            }
        ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Users',
            'intention'  => 'registration',
        ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'fos_user_registration';

        // Or for Symfony < 2.8
        // return 'fos_user_registration';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user_registration';
    }
}
```

So anyone fill the register form and submit. User created and adding the domains to user_domains table but doesn't update the **user** field which must be new user's id. How to do this with automatically? Or have you got any idea to update this **user** column of **user_domains** table with the new user's id?

Thanks for helps to all StackoverFlow :)

Comment: In User::addDomain add $domain->setUser($this); I found your question to be a bit confusing but I think that is what you are asking for.

Comment: This didn't resolved my problem. Problem is when User entity save it must be save to UserDomains entity with new user's id.

Comment: I think your basic approach is flawed.  Take a look at form collections: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add __construct like this to RegistrationType:

```
class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    private $user;

    public  function  __construct(Users $user) {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
```

add setUser function to your DataTransform like this:

```
$domainObj->setUser($this->user);
//and
$domain->setUser($this->user);
```

finally update your controller like this:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new RegistrationType($userEntity), $userEntity);
```

Comment: Just be aware that this approach will not work for Symfony 3.  If you really feel the need for something like this then pass $user via the options parameter in createForm.